# JSON en SQL 17.7 - 'JSON_VALUE' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Necesito recibir un objeto **json** a mi base de datos leerlo y crear una tabla con el contenido de mi json, ya ando trabajando en ello, pero me aparece este error cuando intento utilizar `JSON_VALUE`:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 24
>   'JSON_VALUE' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.

Encontré que para resolver el **Msg 195, Level 16, State 1** podría ocupar esta línea

```
alter database xdb 
set compatibility_level = 120
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error:

> Los valores válidos del nivel de compatibilidad de la base de datos son 90, 100 o 110.

Aquí les dejo mi query y als especificaciones de mi SQL Server, si alguien conoce una forma certera de realizar esta tarea le agradecería mucho. Mi meta es poder recibir y crear un tabla con el contenido exacto del json.

```
use[xdb ]
IF OBJECT_ID('stats_ddl') is not null DROP TABLE stats_ddl


CREATE TABLE stats_ddl(
  id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  year int,
  JsonData nvarchar(300)
);


insert into stats_ddl(year, JsonData) values(2017, '{"Make" : "Volkswagen", "Model" : "Golf"}');
insert into stats_ddl(year, JsonData) values(2017, '{"Make" : "Honda", "Model" : "Civic"}');
insert into stats_ddl(year, JsonData) values(2017, '{"Make" : "Subaru", "Model" : "Impreza"}');

dbcc traceon(3604)
dbcc ind('CGBI_Platform', 'stats_ddl', -1) --obtener el id de la pagina
dbcc page('CGBI_Platform', 1, 839, 3) with tableresults

alter database CGBI_Platform
set compatibility_level = 120

alter table dbo.stats_dll
add make as JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.Make')

select * from stats_ddl
```

Comment: Ese error se debe a la versión de tu motor de base de datos. Dado que tu nivel de compatibilidad es el 110, la versión de tu motor de base de datos es la 11.x (SQL Server 2012). Entiendo que la manipulación de objetos de tipo json fue introducido en la versión 13 (SQL Server 2016), por lo tanto la solución es migrar tu base de datos a una versión superior. Por cierto, los valores de versiones que muestran corresponden a tu manejador, es decir al SQL Server Management Studio, no del motor de BD en sí.

Comment: @Phi, por favor publica tu comentario en el espacio de respuestas.

Comment: pues lo cambié pero sigo sin poder usar json_value o alguna función json, cambiar mi motor de búsqueda desafortunadamente no es una opción necesito poder trabajar con json con mi motor actual. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Realmente no hay mucho por hacer, tu versión actual no soporta el uso de objetos de tipo json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues un amigo me ayudo espero ayudar a todos lo que tengan un problema similar.
Aquí hay una función que traduce cualquier json y devuelve todo en una tabla
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/